# $X^T M X = O$ for indefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$M$ is a symmetric, real, $2 \times 2$ matrix. Why is it true that if one eigenvalue is positive and one is negative ($M$ is indefinite), there exists some nonzero vector $X$ such that $X^T M X = O$ ?

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the path $X_t=te_1+(1-t)e_2$ between eigenvectors of different signs for the eigenvalues then $f(t)=X_t^T M X_t$ takes opposite signs for $t=0$ and $t=1$, whence has a zero. And the zero is not the zero vector.

Comment: It's probably obvious, but I take the last line to be implicitly using the fact that $X_t=0$ can only occur if $e_1$ and $e_2$ are parallel (which of course they are not). (They should in fact be _orthogonal_, but one hardly needs that for this argument.)

Comment: Yes, I used (implicitly) that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are independent. Indeed, it is not of importance that they are orthogonal (w.r.t. the standard scalar product).

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and Euclidean length 1, and $v_2$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ and Euclidean length 1. Now, examine how $X = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2$ fits into the expectation value equation:
$$\begin{align}
X^T M X & = (a_1 v_1^T + a_2 v_2^T)M(a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2) \\
& = a_1^2 \lambda_1 + 2 a_2 a_1 v_1^T v_2 (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) + a_2^2 \lambda_2 \\
& = a_1^2 \lambda_1 + a_2^2 \lambda_2. \end{align}$$
Notice how the final line can only equal $0$ if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ have opposite signs. When that is the case, you can solve for the relationship between $a_1$ and $a_2$ that make the expectation zero.